# Проверка выхода за нижнюю границу вектора С++

Tags: c++, векторы

Пишу код для реализации шифра Цезаря со сдвигом влево(сдвигает каждую букву введеного текста на n-е количество символов по алфавиту влево). Нашла следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string encrypt(string input) {
    vector<char> word(input.begin(), input.end());
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)input.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)alphabet.length(); j++) {
            if (word[i] == alphabet[j]) {
                word[i] = alphabet[(j + 3) % 26];

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    string str(word.begin(), word.end());
    return str;
} 


int main() {
string text = "abc";
cout << text << endl;

string textencrypt = encrypt(text);
cout << textencrypt << endl;
}
```

Код работает для сдвига вправо, но при попытке сдвигать букву влево - выходит за нижнюю границу. Как можно реализовать проверку и переход на последний элемент(при выпадании)?

Comment: вы не выходите из цикла из-за фигурной скобки `word[i] = alphabet[(j + 3) % 26];   **  } **`

Comment: покажите **код** который сдвигает влево. эта тонкость очень важна.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, мой косяк, в исходнике скобки не было ) но и с ней тоже не работает корректно при сдвиге влево

Comment: @AlexGlebe, так как этот код для сдвига вправо, то сдвигает вправо. Думала просто изменить знак вот тут:
word[i] = alphabet[(j + 3) % 26];

Тогда сдвигает влево корректно. Но если, например, сдвинуть букву А на 7 позиций, то выдает непредсказуемый результат

Comment: почитаёте ответ [Некорректно работает перемещение по полю 8х8 клавишами W,A,S,D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453636/Некорректно-работает-перемещение-по-полю-8х8-клавишами-w-a-s-d/1453644#1453644)

Comment: у вас так : `word[i] = alphabet[(j + 26 - 7) % 26];`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, сработало, спасибо, Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word[i] = alphabet[(j + X + 26) % 26]
```

Где X - сдвиг любого знака

Это исправит проблему с отрицательным остатком от деления